# "Command 'netsh wlan show profiles' returned non-zero exit status 1"

Tags: python, subprocess

```
import subprocess

def wifi_passwords():
    profiles_data = subprocess.check_output('netsh wlan show profiles').decode('utf-8').split('\n')
    # print(profiles_data)

    profiles = [i.split(':')[1].strip() for i in profiles_data if 'All User Profile' in i]
    # print(profiles)

    for profile in profiles:
        profile_info = subprocess.check_output(f'netsh wlan show profile {profile} key clear').decode('utf-8').split('\n')
        # print(profile_info)
        try:
            password = [i.split(':')[1].strip() for i in profile_info if 'Key Content' in i]
        except IndexError:
            password = None

        # print(f'Profile: {profile}\nPassword: {password}')

        with open(file='wifi_pasword.txt', mode='a', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            file.write(f'Profile: {profile}\nPassword: {password}')

wifi_passwords()
```

Ошибка:

```
  File "E:\venv\Lesson\venv\prikolu\wifipasword.py", line 23, in <module>
    wifi_passwords()
  File "E:\venv\Lesson\venv\prikolu\wifipasword.py", line 4, in wifi_passwords
    profiles_data = subprocess.check_output('netsh wlan show profiles').decode('utf-8').split('\n')
  File "C:\Users\yerko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 420, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "C:\Users\yerko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 524, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'netsh wlan show profiles' returned non-zero exit status 1.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: "Command 'netsh wlan show profiles' returned non-zero exit status 1." - выясняйте чем команда не довольна.

Comment: Так а как? Я новичок

Comment: Добавьте в вызов `check_output` параметр `shell=True`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71090925/why-does-netsh-wlan-show-profiles-return-non-zero-exit-status-1

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Я это читал не помогло

Comment: А shell=True не помогло

Comment: Вы элементарно пробовали эту команду просто выполнить в терминале на компьютере?